# How can GDB de-reference the same pointer in two different ways?

Tags: c++, types, gdb

I have two pointer variables that point at the same address:

```
(gdb) p a
$1 = (MyClass *) 0x7fd7251e58f8
(gdb) p store._head._ptr
$2 = (MyClass *) 0x7fd7251e58f8
```

But when I dereference them, I get different results:

```
(gdb) p *a
$3 = {<MyBase> = {_state = 0}, price = 1, quantity = 1,
      arrivalTime = 1430087034755819, matchTime = 
      "-18:23:53.000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\035"}
(gdb) p *store._head._ptr
$4 = {<MyBase> = {_state = 0}, price = 1, quantity = 1,
      arrivalTime = 1430087034755819, matchTime =
      "20150427-18:23:53.000"}
```

See the difference? It's only in the field `matchTime`. So I checked the relative offset of the field in both instances:

```
(gdb) p ((char*)&a->matchTime) - (char*)a
$5 = 28
(gdb) p ((char*)&store._head._ptr->matchTime) - (char*)store._head._ptr
$6 = 20
```

I can understand why I'd get a 20, since there's 3 32-bit integers, followed by a 64-bit integer, total of 3*4+8=20 bytes.

Clearly, GDB thinks that both pointer variables are of the same type name, `MyClass*`. But it clearly also thinks that each variable is of a different type!

**How can I dig deeper? How can I even distinguish between each of the types?**

UPDATE: The problem was a linker issue. The code was linking with the wrong version of the library and headers. That caused the pointer variable accessed through `store._head._ptr` to have the same (old) type information as the rest of the library code, while the pointer variable `a` had incompatible (newer) type information.

My question still stands, though. How did GDB know that there was a difference? **How can I ask GDB which type it used for dereferencing?**

Using `ptype` on each variable yielded the same output of `MyClass*` type information. But still GDB did *different* dereferencing on each pointer variable.

I tried using `nm` and `objdump` on the executable and library, but I couldn't use their output to distinguish between the different types.

**So How can I query GDB in greater detail about the types and debug information it has about every variable?**

Comment: Please provide a minimal testcase that reproduces the issue. Just as always. (Six years!!!)

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I wish I could, but I couldn't produce a more minimal example than providing my entire project. Each minimal example I made, didn't exhibit the same behavior. Also, my question isn't about the code - it's about how to use GDB (or other tools?) to explore the symbols and types.

Comment: _"Each minimal example I made, didn't exhibit the same behavior."_ Right, well, that's precisely the problem here, isn't it? What you're telling me is that this problem is caused by something in your project that we can't see. Something odd that is making GDB behave in unexpected ways (and, no, we can't just approach that generically!) So how do you expect us to know what it is? You will _have_ to keep trying to make a minimal testcase. It's not a choice; it's a requirement.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point. Which mean I've failed to convey it in the question. I'm asking something more like "What GDB commands can I use to tell me why GDB is treating each pointer variable as if it were a different type". Also, I've solved the *cause*, but I still would like to know how GDB could have helped me, and why it behaved the way it did.

Comment: Linker issue, I edited the answer with the update, and hopefully a better explanation of what I'm asking. (Sorry to waste your time so early in the morning.)

Answer (score 1):

Right, so we can see now that you invoked Undefined Behaviour. It is probably possible, with enough time and effort, to reproduce the problem and use the GDB source code to trace the precise sequence of events that led to the symptoms you witnessed. However, this could fill a (boring) PhD thesis and is utterly without merit. When you see strange, inconsistent behaviours like this, *something is wrong* and it is in your best interest to go finding the source of the UB before attempting any further diagnostics with the affected tool/output/mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

> Using ptype on each variable yielded the same output of MyClass* type information.

But using `ptype *a` and `ptype *store._head._ptr` should show the difference.